# why proxies doesn't work when switching from requests to selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, proxies

I tried other solutions here on **Stackoverflow**, bit non of them worked for me.

I'm trying to configure **selenium** with a **proxy**, It worked with **requests** library, I used this command:

```
requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com', proxies={'https':'https://3.0.32.21:22881'})
```

It gave me a **valid status code**, which means It's working:

```
<Response [200]>
```

But when I try the same **proxy** with **Selenium**, It doesn't work at all, here is what I tried regarding **Selenium** configuration with the **proxy**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

PROXY = "3.0.32.21:22881"
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
capabilities['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
capabilities['proxy'] = {
        "httpProxy": PROXY,
        "ftpProxy": PROXY,
        "sslProxy": PROXY,
        "noProxy": None,
        "proxyType": "MANUAL",
        "class": "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
        "autodetect": False}
            
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
```

Here is a **screenshot** for the **automated browser session** as well:
[image]

Is there something wrong with my selenium configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue for me **switching** to the **Firefox** driver solved the issue.

If you wanna stick to chrome maybe you can try that approach:

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={PROXY}')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```